# Difference when mounting NFS using either net use or mount within Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, nfs

I'm currently looking at mounting an NFS to use within a load balanced environment. The host is Ubuntu and the clients (using client for NFS) are using Windows 2012 R2.

I was wondering which command is better to use either 'net use' or the 'mount' command and what the difference between the two are in terms of mounting and if they both just use the NFS client driver within windows and there is no actual difference?

Answer (score 2):

The `mount` command is used to mount NFS based network shares whereas "net use" is used for connecting/disconnecting from a SMB network resource or viewing connection information.

Either to use "mount" command or "net use" command would totally depend upon the type of network share that you would be mounting and would not make any difference if the enviroment is load balanced or not.

Since 2008, both are capable of mounting NFS shares. But until today `mount`cannot view, edit or do anything else with SMB logon-tokens than mount a ressource.

Comment: Okay I'm running an NFS server on Ubuntu and using net use to mount to share, I'm wondering if using mount would be a better alternative?

Comment: As long as you don't need to manipulate you tokens (or get rid of them with /delete), the one is like the other.